# How to edit a dictionary from within a running python file?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I have a program and i was trying to edit a dictionary from user input in the file.
This is what i have:

```
def main():
    dataInfo = {"data1":"12345", "data2":"abc123"}

    addInfo = input(":")
    addInfoValue = input(":")
    dataInfo[addInfo] = addInfoValue

    wantedInfo = input(":")

    try:
        if dataInfo[wantedInfo]:
            print(dataInfo[wantedInfo])
    except KeyError:
        exit()

main()
```

I made this but whenever i restart the program the stuff i add to the dictionary is removed.

I was wondering if there was a way for the data written into the dictionary was saved. I was aware of something to do with having multiple files but am not sure how to do that.

This isn't the exact file layout and stuff btw. Just the stuff im having trouble with.

Also a way to remove certain parts of the dictionary would help too.

Comment: Dictionaries are stored within memory. They won't be saved across multiple runs. If you want to save data between runs,  you can look into Python file IO, which will save data onto a file that you can write to and read from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the program, the variables are stored in temporary memory (i.e. RAM). This memory gets cleared when you restart the program.

if you want the stuffs to be persisted, then you would need to somehow store them in a persistent storage, text file or database

here is an example:

```
import json

some_dict = {'mykey':'myvalue'}

with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
  # json.dumps will convert your dict into string
  file.write(json.dumps(some_dict))

# read the data from text file
load_dict = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
  text_data = file.read()
  # json.loads do the opposite of json.dumps
  load_dict = json.loads(text_data)
```

So what you want to do is everytime the user input something, you save the dict into text file and at the beginning of the program load the text file into dict

Answer (score 0):

You can't store you dictionary without write it to a file because it is managed within the memory.

You can write your dictionary as a `json` file and in the next run you will be able to read the already written values by reading the file, update it and write it again to the same file (or different one):

```
import json
with open('path/to/file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dataInfo, f)
```

and in the next run, you will be able to read it:

```
with open('path/to_file.json','r') as f:
    dataInfo = json.load(f)
```

In order to delete keys for dictionary, you can use `pop()` func:

```
dataInfo.pop("data1") # data1 key will be removed from the dict
```